# How to find the formulaaa

Tags: probability

A palindrome is a string m such that if we write m in reverse order , it will produce string m again. for example, 101,111,1001 and 10111101 are palindrome whereas 110,011,1011 and 10110101 are not palindrome. determine the probability of a given binary string of length n to be a palindrome. then,determine the probability of binary string of length 55 to be palindrome?  How to find it formula

Answer (score 2):

I would use the fundamental counting principle to find the number of possible palindromes for a string of length $n$, divided by the total possible binary strings, dealing with the cases where $n$ is odd and $n$ is even separately.

For example, let's examine a case where $n$ is even, so suppose $n=6$.
Then the first digit could be either 0 or 1 (2 possibilities), but the last digit has to be the same as the first (1 possibility).
Similarly, the second digit could be either 0 or 1, but the second-last digit has to be the same as the second digit.
Also, the third digit could be either 0 or 1, but the third-last digit has to be the same as the third digit.

So the total number of possible binary palindromes for $n=6$ is $2*2*2*1*1*1=8$.
The total possible binary strings of length $n=6$ is $2*2*2*2*2*2=64$.
So the probability that the binary string is a palindrome is $\frac{8}{64}=\frac{1}{8}$.

Now, let's examine a case where $n$ is odd, so suppose $n=7$.
Then the first digit could be either 0 or 1 (2 possibilities), but the last digit has to be the same as the first (1 possibility).
Similarly, the second digit could be either 0 or 1, but the second-last digit has to be the same as the second digit.
Also, the third digit could be either 0 or 1, but the third-last digit has to be the same as the third digit.
The fourth digit has no palindrome pair, so it can be either 0 or 1.

So the total number of possible binary palindromes for $n=7$ is $2*2*2*2*1*1*1=16$.
The total possible binary strings of length $n=7$ is $2*2*2*2*2*2*2=128$.
So the probability that the binary string of length $n=7$ is a palindrome is $\frac{16}{128}=\frac{1}{8}$.

I hope this helps you generalize for any $n$ and for $n=55$.

Comment: How to know that total number of possible binary palindromes for n=6 is 2∗2∗2∗1∗1∗1=8?

Comment: In the equation 2*2*2*1*1*1, the first 2 represents the number of possibilities for the first digit (it can be either 0 or 1), the second 2 represents the number of possibilities for the second digit (it can be either 0 or 1), the third 2 represents the number of possibilities for the third digit (it can be either 0 or 1), the 1 represents the number of possibilities for the fourth digit (it has to be the same as the third digit, so only 1 possibility), the next 1 is the options for the fifth digit (same as the second, so 1 possibility) and the last 1 is the options for the last digit.

Comment: How about n=4 n=55?

Comment: How to do for   N=4? .. n=55?

Comment: For n=4, it would be (2*2*1*1)/(2*2*2*2)=(1/2)^2

For n = 55, it would be (2^27*2*1^27)/(2)^55=(1/2)^27, this is the same as the formula below

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the string is odd, say $2N+1$, then the probability that it is a palindrome will be

$$
\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]^N
$$

that is the let the left $N$ letters be anything, then the right $N$ letters must then match the left $N$ letters, each with probability $1/2$.

Similarly if the length of the string is even, say $2N$ then the probability that is a palindrome is

$$
\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]^N
$$

A binary string of length $55$ has probability

$$
\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]^{27}\approx 7.4505\times 10^{-9}
$$

of being a palindrome.

Comment: How to know that length 55  has probability ....as N=27?

Comment: Because 55=2*27+1.

Comment: Why odd and even have the same formulae?

Comment: n=6 and n=7 have the same formulae because the middle digit in n=7 can be anything since it doesn't have a pair, so the number of palindromes for n=7 is two times greater than the number of palindromes for n=6, but the number of total possibilities is also two times greater for n=7 compared to n=6, so the 2's in the numerator and denominator cancel out.

Note that n=7 and n=8 do not have the same formulae.

Comment: If we write the answer as above. It correct or not?

Comment: It is correct.  Note that in this formula, for n=6, we get (1/2)^3=1/8.  For n=7, we get (1/2)^3=1/8.  For n=8, we get (1/2)^4=1/16.

Comment: Yes @PhimPhaCheeChee it is correct. I sincerely hope you spend enough time with the formula so that you yourself are certain that it is correct.